# C++ SFML creating a vector of shapes and drawing them in a function

Tags: c++, function, vector, sfml

I wanted to create a vector of randomly placed squares and draw them to the screen, tried passing a reference to a vector and i couldn't get that to work :(

consumable.h

```
#ifndef CONSUMABLE_H
#define CONSUMABLE_H

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

class consumable
{
    public:
     consumable();
    virtual ~consumable();

    vector<RectangleShape> fCreateConsumable(vector<RectangleShape>& vConsumable);
    void fDrawTarget(float x, float y, RenderWindow &thatWindow);

protected:

private:
    vector<RectangleShape> vConsumable;
    RectangleShape _consumable;
};
```

consumable.cpp

```
#include "consumable.h"

consumable::consumable()
{
    //ctor
}

consumable::~consumable()
{
    //dtor
}
void consumable::fCreateConsumable(){
    int consumableX{0}, consumableY{0};

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        consumableX = (rand() % 31) + 1;
        consumableY = (rand() % 22) + 1;
        _consumable.setPosition((consumableX * 25), (consumableY * 25));
        _consumable.setSize(sf::Vector2f(25.0f,25.0f));
        _consumable.setFillColor(sf::Color::Magenta);
        vConsumable.push_back(_consumable);
    }
}
void consumable::fDrawTarget(float x, float y, RenderWindow &thatWindow){
    void fCreateConsumable();

    for(int i{0};i< vConsumable.size();i++){
        thatWindow.draw(vConsumable[i]);
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include "consumable.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    consumable Consumable;
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(800,750), "C++ Snake"); 

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
          switch(event.type)
          {
            case Event::Closed:
              window.close();
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
        }
        window.clear();
        Consumable.fDrawTarget(25,25,window);
        window.display();
    }
    std::cout << "Finished" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to loop over

Comment: You have included a copy of main.cpp when you meant to include consumable.h.  Please [edit] your question to fix this.

Comment: I would declare `consumableX` and `consumableY` as `const int` within the loop.  Similarly, I would make `_consumable` a local within `fCreateConsumable` (probably within the loop again).  In `fDrawTarget` I would write the loop as `for(const auto& item: vConsumable)){    thatWindow.draw(item);}`

Comment: And finally, in what way "couldn't you get that to work"?  Compiler error message (please show it exactly)?  Unexpected output? (What?)  Crash?  (Where?)

Comment: added consumable.h, as for the error nothing would be drawn onto the screen, i tried finding a way to look into the vector with the debugging tool but I couldn't find anything useful

Comment: I'm currently trying to convert my original project into an object orientated format because I suck at classes etc. can post the wall of text in my original main.cpp but thats really ugly to  look at even for me

Comment: Where do you close `void consumable::fDrawTarget()` or have you missed a closing bracket on the for-loop? You should also remove `void` in front of `fCreateConsumable();` in that function if you want to use it in `fDrawTarget()`.

Comment: @Chringo I just missed the brace off its there.

Comment: @MartinBonner  error: variable or field 'fCreateConsumable' declared void| theres the error

Comment: @Chringo I'm an idiot :P its runs now EDIT: it now infinitely draws 3 shapes (modified how many i wanted) every frame

Comment: Right, so what's left is getting your `consumable` class drawn from `main`? Just to be clear, you've shown us the entire `consumable::fDrawTarget()` but just missed the closing bracket? E: Reading your last comment seems like you got it figured out.

Comment: @Chringo almost! i just need to stop it after it draws 3 however im not familiar with (const auto& item: vConsumable) so I have no idea how to correct it

Comment: @Chringo https://pastebin.com/jzezWZs3 there is a pastebin with gif to make it easier to understand

Comment: Place a breakpoint in `fDrawTarget` and step into `fCreateConsumable`. It has to do with your vector. I'll write an answer but I think you can figure it out too!

Comment: well that is silly of me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your class `consumable`, I'd start by making `_consumable` local and refactor `fCreateConsumable` adding another function.

```
class consumable
{
    public:
    // ...    
    vector<RectangleShape> fCreateConsumable(vector<RectangleShape>& vConsumable);
    void fDrawTarget(float x, float y, RenderWindow &thatWindow);
    void UpdatePositions();
private:
    vector<RectangleShape> vConsumable;
};
```

By removing `fCreateConsumable` from `fDrawTarget` you can avoid creating new `RectangleShape`, reuse the old three ones, and update them with new positions.

```
void consumable::UpdatePositions(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i{0};i< vConsumable.size();i++){
        vConsumable[i].setPosition(((rand() % 31) + 1) * 25, ((rand() % 22) + 1) * 25);
    }
}
void consumable::fCreateConsumable(){
    int consumableX{0}, consumableY{0};
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        consumableX = (rand() % 31) + 1;
        consumableY = (rand() % 22) + 1;
        _consumable.setPosition((consumableX * 25), (consumableY * 25));
        _consumable.setSize(sf::Vector2f(25.0f,25.0f));
        _consumable.setFillColor(sf::Color::Magenta);
        vConsumable.push_back(_consumable);
    }
}
void consumable::fDrawTarget(float x, float y, RenderWindow &thatWindow){
    UpdatePositions();
    for(int i{0};i< vConsumable.size();i++){
        thatWindow.draw(vConsumable[i]);
    }
}
```

Personally, I would move out `UpdatePositions` from `fDrawTarget` too and make the drawcall a const function. That way you separate the update and the rendering. If you don't, move `UpdatePositions` to private scope.